# Assigning students in classroom - Flow in networks?

Tags: algorithm, network-flow

I have one room, that is opened few days in a week, every day in different hours (7:00-14:42, ...)

I have multiple students, each can visit the room in different days, in different hours (students may have time to visit the room in multiple days)

I need to assign all (or the most I can) students into the room with following rules:

- Each student have to visit the room once in the week for exactly 50 minutes
- After (only) 2nd student in the room, the room will be unavailable for following 20 minutes

Example of the second rule:

```
+---------------+-----------------+
|     TIME      |     INFO        |
+---------------+-----------------+
|  7:00 - 7:50  |  Student 1      |
|  7:50 - 8:40  |  Student 2      |
|  8:40 - 9:00  | Mandatory break | // No student may be here
|  9:00 - 9:50  |  Student 3      |
|  9:50 - 10:40 |  Student 4      |
| 10:40 - 11:30 |  Student 5      |
|     . . .     |     . . .       |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

How can I solve this? I've thought of using flow in networks, but I encountered a problem.

Let's say I have this flow. When Student gets connected to Time, flow should go through *all* Groups, that contains the Time. If any of these groups are occupied, the flow cannot go there. So when the student gets connected to Time, all Times, that might overlap with student's Time, are disabled. But I don't know how to build an algorithm, that would allow that.

[image: Flow in network]

Could you please tell me how to make an algorithm to make this work? I don't know how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: This is quite an informal description. What's there to optimize? Just fill every day in a greedy manner: first slot, second slot, break, ..., until day is over. Continue with the next day and remaining students? Why does that not work? I can't see anything in your description given a reason it should not (e.g. student preferences). If the problem get's more hard (some missing rules), i'm somewhat sceptic about using network-flow approaches (at least to combat alternative approaches which are naturally exponential in general like Constraint-Programming or Integer-programming).

Comment: There will be students which times will overlay, so I'll have to choose one student from like 10 or even more. When I do it the simple way (students with less time have higher priority or something like this), I always find input, where this doesn't work. And I don't want to use bruteforce when there is better way how to do it - and I want to find the better way.